# Sending JSON data in the body of an Alamofire Request

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I'm trying to make an api call to submit some data using `Alamofire` (version 4.0). The trouble i'm having is that when making the call I get a response from the server that the JSON data was not in a valid format.

Is there a way to check if the data data is being serialized correctly in Alamofire?

I have tried many of the solutions currently on StackOverflow and cannot find a solution. Thanks for your help.

**This should be the format of the request body:**

```
{
"reference_id": "Test001",
"data": {
    "type": "step",
    "data": {
        "2015-08-02": 8574
    }
}
}
```

**My Swift code:**

```
let params: [String:Any] = [
        "reference_id": "someName",
        "data": [
            "type" : "step",
            "data": [
                "2015-08-02": 8574
            ]
        ]
    ]

    print(params)

    if let userToken = userToken {
        let request = Alamofire.request(url+"API.php?Action=SaveHealthData", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString(completionHandler: { response in
            print(response)
        })
    }
```

**The error I'm getting is:**

> **Warning**:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in **/var/www/html/API/SaveHealthData.php** on line **8**
>       {"error":"data not in valid json format"}

Comment: Remove [String:Any]  from let params: [String:Any] and use only let params = [ your value]

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work unfortunately swift requires the type to be declared in this way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the solutions of your problem,

```
var dataDict : [String : Any] = [:];

dataDict["type"] = "Step"
dataDict["data"] = ["2015-08-02": 8574];

let params: [String:Any] = ["reference_id": "someName",
                            "data": String.toJSonString(data: dataDict)];
```

Here **toJSonString** is an extension of String

```
static func toJSonString(data : Any) -> String {

        var jsonString = "";

        do {

            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .prettyPrinted)
            jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return jsonString;
}
```

Happy **Coding**

Comment: Thank you this was super helpful :)

Comment: Cool  Answer :) (y)